# How to make does not allow space in HTML text input

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am implementing Registration form using HTML and PHP. When user registered, one table with username will be create in mysql. In this case, Table is completely create in mysql if the name does not have space. Therefore I would like to defined the user name text field not to allow space " ". Could someone please help me out from this.

Thanks.

Comment: You would have to remove the spaces in the PHP code

Comment: I really think, it is not a good idea to create a table for each user; especially not NAMED with the users name, what if a user name is equal to a reserved word in mysql? If you add some kind of prefix, this would be not a problem. And of course, you can enclose the name of your table with the ´ character, should allow spaces in your table name. be aware that (at least it was the case earlier) on linux systems the table names can be case sensitive (maybe this has changed ... please try)

Comment: The Unicode catalogue has millions of characters, you can't possibly compose a full list of the "invalid" ones—and regular white space [is not actually invalid](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=ee325427f1165c8467150bb19e2a8742). As said, this design is a potential headache. Whatever you're trying to accomplish, there're better ways.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.